# JQuery div fall down effect onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to get a large logo (in the header of my site) to fall down into the header area on load. And so this is the only jquery function that I can find that seems to fit the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/apHLu/279/

```
var $dropDiv = $('#dropDiv');
   $('#holder a').on('click', function() {
    // get position of the element we clicked on
    var offset = $(this).offset();

    // get width/height of click element
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    var w = $(this).outerWidth();

    // get width/height of drop element
    var dh = $dropDiv.outerHeight();
    var dw = $dropDiv.outerWidth();

    // determine middle position
    var initLeft = offset.left + ((w/2) - (dw/2));

    // animate drop
    $dropDiv.css({
            left: initLeft,
            top: $(window).scrollTop() - dh,
            opacity: 0,
            display: 'block'
        }).animate({
            left: initLeft,
            top: offset.top - dh,
            opacity: 1
        }, 300, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

I basically want to know, is it possible to switch the click trigger to an onload call? I don't want to be muddling around trying to get it to work if it's not possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apHLu/280/).  `$(function() { ... });` is short for 'Document is ready'.  I also wrapped the function in `setTimeout();`, because it was firing a little quick to see the full effect.  Change the second parameter in `setTimeout` to adjust the time it waits to fire...

**Updated** (per @coby suggestion)**:** If you do have a large amount of images you could change `$(function() {` to `window.onload(function() {`.  Ready doesn't wait for all the images to be completely loaded.

Comment: You may also want to wrap it in `$(window).load(function(){ ... });` so that it's fired once all images (including the logo) have loaded.